# How to run a jar file generated by maven in Jenkins Job Builder

Tags: jenkins, jar, jenkins-pipeline

I have a maven project (assume it is just a simple hello-world java program) in git.  Now I want to (1) create the jar file; (2) run this jar file. How can I do this through Jenkins Job Builder hourly (like every one hour Jenkins will build the jar file, and execute it)? Thanks.

Comment: means you want executable jar file, Can you explain more?

Comment: Hello Sandip, generally yes, want a jar and execute in Jenkins job. Answer given by Madhava below basically solves my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, create a Jenkins `Freestyle Project`.

```
TZ=Asia/Kolkata
0 */1 * * *
```

Please add the above code in `Build periodically` box. It will run your code once an hour. For creating the jar file,

```
cd '<your project location in the disk>'
mvn clean install
```

Now this will build your jar file. To run the jar file,

```
cd 'target'
java -jar <project jar file name>.jar
```

So total script will be like :

```
cd '<your project location in the disk>'
mvn clean install
cd 'target'
java -jar <project jar file name>.jar
```

Add the above code to `Execute shell` block in `Build` -> `Add build step` -> `Execute shell` in the job configuration. Hope this is what you are looking for.